# Python How to read a line and then ask the user if they would like to move onto the next line?

Tags: python-3.x

The program I am trying to run is to read a file that contains the following.

```
Jeffery, Ben, 5/5/2020, 2000
testinglast, testfirst, 17/5/2020, 240
```

This is the code I am using to read it:

```
def fileRead():
    global nameLast
    global nameFirst
    pageLine()
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            nameLast, nameFirst, date, points = line.split(',')
            name_check_read()
            print(f'Last name: {nameLast}\n'
                  f'First name: {nameFirst}\n'
                  f'Date: {date}\n'
                  f'Points: {points}\n')
Output looks like this:
Last name: Jeffery
First name:  Ben
Date:  5/5/2020
Points:  2000

Last name: testinglast
First name:  testfirst
Date:  17/5/2020
Points:  240
```

How do I make it so after the first user is displayed that it asks me to do the next user or just end the program? Thank you for your help.

Comment: check out `rawinput()` in python

Answer (score 0):

For continuation ask for user input using `input()` and check if wants to continue and for exiting the program use `sys.exit()` which is in sys library

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Simple `break` [statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html) will also work for you to come out of the loop.

Your code will look like this if you ask for continuation and exit if wrong input provided.

```
import sys

def fileRead():
    global nameLast
    global nameFirst
    pageLine()
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        choice = "Y"

        for line in f:
            if choice == "Y":

                nameLast, nameFirst, date, points = line.split(',')
                name_check_read()
                print(f'Last name: {nameLast}\n'
                      f'First name: {nameFirst}\n'
                      f'Date: {date}\n'
                      f'Points: {points}\n')
                choice=input("Enter 'Y' to continue")
            else:
                sys.exit(0)
```

Output looks like this:
Last name: Jeffery
First name:  Ben
Date:  5/5/2020
Points:  2000

Last name: testinglast
First name:  testfirst
Date:  17/5/2020
Points:  240

Comment: That would work but I need it to display just the first user, and then it asks if you would like to read the next user, then if they say yes it will show the next user.

Comment: updated the answer with your comment, this will first print the first line and then ask for input if "Y" then continue or else exit from program